# Perché si usava mettere un trattino sotto e sopra alcune vocali?

Tags: letters

[image: Ferrovie della regione Friuli Venezia Giulia]

Qual è il significato del trattino visibile sotto e sopra ad alcune vocali di quella frase?

Perché  la prima "E" di Venezia ha un trattino sopra ma la seconda "E" non lo ha?

Comment: Bisognerebbe chiederlo al grafico! Scherzi a parte, non c'è nessun motivo linguistico o ortografico, ma solo una scelta “estetica” di usare delle lettere originali.

Comment: Dubito che il cartello sia “antico”: il passaggio della ferrovia Udine-Cividale alla gestione regionale risale al 2005 ([secondo Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrovia_Udine-Cividale)). Non c'è alcun significato.

Comment: Può essere una scelta estetica, ma in questo caso non capisco perché differenziare la seconda "O" dalla prima IN "AUTONOMA" e la prima  "E" dalla seconda in "VENEZIA". Non credo sia un caso, credo ci sia un criterio con il quale quelle lettere sono state scelte

Comment: Non direi proprio, così come non c'è un criterio per cui due N hanno una grazia in alto a sinistra e una no, per la grazia su una E sì e una no, e per la seconda I di GIULIA, più piccola e rialzata.

Comment: Aggiungo per completezza che i trattini sopra alcune vocali si usano sì, ma in tutt'alto contesto: in latino e nella traslitterazione di altre lingue per indicare le vocali lunghe, mentre per le brevi si usa una specie di semicerchio aperto verso l'alto. Quindi, per esempio, se vogliamo evidenziare la quantità vocalica, *rosă* è il nominativo mentre *rosā* è l'ablativo. Altri usi che non siano estremamente specialistici (o di fantasia come in questo caso) non esistono.

Comment: I vote to close this question because it is not clear.

Comment: Forse i trattini identificano l'accento da usare nella lingua friulana. Il Friuli ha portato avanti il processo di riconoscimento del friuliano, quindi potrebbe essere una notazione locale

Comment: (La parola sotto che inizia con F assomiglia al commento in inglese che ho fatto d'istinto alle scelte grafiche di chi ha fatto questo logo...)

Comment: @DaG vorrei sapere dove e' il materiale su cui hai basato la tua affermazione cosi' sicura che non ci siano motivi linguistici/ortografici ma e' solo una scelta estetica e che l'uso sia di pura fantasia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I trattini non hanno alcun significato linguistico e sono solo un accorgimento grafico.

Per dirimere la questione, ho posto la domanda direttamente all'Ufficio per le relazioni con il pubblico della Regione Autonoma Friuli Venezia Giulia, tramite il loro [modulo in rete](http://filodiretto.regione.fvg.it/filodiretto2011/filodiretto/Osserva.aspx), che mi ha risposto in modo cortese e sollecito:

> Sig. Gewurz buongiorno,
>
> i "trattini" presenti nel logotipo della Regione Autonoma Friuli Venezia Giulia non hanno nessuna implicazione di carattere linguistico e non esprimono alcun suono dialettale. Sono una scelta puramente grafica che prende spunto direttamente dalle iscrizioni lapidee romane di Aquileia.
>
> Cordiali saluti.
>
> Grazie per il suo interessamento ed il suo contributo
>
> Filo diretto con i cittadini
>   Ufficio relazioni con il pubblico
>   Valter Cabas - URP
>   regurp.ud@regione.fvg.it
>
> http://filodiretto.regione.fvg.it

Comment: Grazie per il tuo interessamento :)

Comment: grazie per aver postato la fonte

Comment: Di niente: grazie a voi, e in particolare a @ManuelBitto per aver sollevato una questione interessante.

Answer (score -2):

Quoto JoeTaras. Il Friulano, come linguaggio, mantiene le varie indicazioni fonetiche, anni fa c'era una pubblicazione in proposito per un dizionario Italiano-friulano. È però la prima volta che li vedo usati per parole in italiano piuttosto che puro dialetto.

Sono d'accordo che non può essere una semplice scelta di genere di carattere tipografico visto che alcune vocali hanno forma normale, non è da escludere però che la scelta di porre il trattino al di sotto della lettera sia una cosa inventata per l'occasione. Visto che nelle parole dialettali usano sia l'accento circonflesso che quello grave (Friuli per esempio lo si scrive Friûl in dialetto) possibile che qui forse abbiano deciso di renderli con trattino sopra e trattino sotto nel tentativo di portare l'uso dialettale su parole Italiane?

Comment: «non può essere una semplice scelta di genere di carattere tipografico visto che alcune vocali hanno forma normale»: che discorso è? Non c'è niente di strano che in uno stesso alfabeto, persino di quelli non ornamentali, sia previsto più di un glifo per la stessa lettera. Non parliamo poi di titoli, loghi e insegne, come in questo caso. Sarebbe un po' come chiedersi il significato linguistico del fatto che nel [logo della Coca Cola](http://tinyurl.com/zr4b8yx) le due “C” maiuscole hanno forme diverse.

Comment: Ogni serie tipografica ha delle precise regole e struttura. In una serie tipografica non hai la scelta tra 4 o 5 tipi di lettera da usare a caso. Eventualmente un set tipografico dimostrera' anche una variazione di carattere dovuta al segno diatrico. Non avrebbe senso che il grafico sia andato ad applicare variazioni a casaccio. Stai davvero confrontando un insegna della regione con un logo inventato a scopo pubblicitario che ha piu' una vicinanza al disegno come spirito? che discorso e'? a questo punto perche' non mettere pure la rovescia del set di scrittura dei bambini?

Comment: E tanto per aggiungere: nel logo della Cocacola il carattere tipografico usato e' derivato con pochi cambiamenti da un tipo di scrittura chiamata Spenceriana, e come molte scritture ornate anche questa ha delle regole di calligrafia, incluso il modo di legare i fronzoli alle altre lettere come l'entrata della C nella L. Magari per questo si puo' interpellare qualcuno dell'Associazione Calligrafica Italiana?

Comment: «In una serie tipografica non hai la scelta tra 4 o 5 tipi di lettera da usare a caso»: dipende. Ci sono caratteri che ne hanno: si chiamano “stylistic alternates”. Da' un'occhiata [qui](http://creativepro.com/typetalk-the-five-best-and-most-underused-features-of-opentype-fonts/) (sotto “Alternate characters”), [qui](http://help.typekit.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1789736-syntax-for-opentype-features-in-css#salt) etc., e questi sono solo i primi link che ho trovato al volo, oppure in qualunque testo serio di tipografia.

Comment: L'“insegna della regione” è un oggetto grafico creato da qualcuno, esattamente come quella della Coca Cola. E probabilmente questo qualcuno ha cercato di distinguere sé e l'oggetto che creava, anziché comporlo in modo ovvio con un font usuale. (Non posso esprimermi sulla “rovescia del set” etc. perché non so che cosa sia, scusa.)